# Time complexity to compute Rand Index

Tags: clustering, algorithms

Suppose we have a set $S$ with $n$ elements, and let $\{X_1,\ldots,X_r\}$ and $\{Y_1,\ldots,Y_s\}$ be two partitions (clusterings) of $S$. I would like to know what is the time complexity for the algorithm that computes the Rand Index between these two partitions as a function of $n,r$ and $s$.

I am working on a special case where the partitions are always of a particular form, and for this case I proved an alternative formula that allows me to compute the Rand Index in $\mathbf{O}(rs)$. Thus, I would like to compare the complexity to the general case. Thank you!

Comment: Construct the [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index#The_contingency_table) and go on from there.

Comment: But how many operations does it take to construct it?

Comment: Tabulating data that have been assigned cluster identifiers requires at most two passes over the data (one to determine $r$ and $s$ and a second to do the counting and store the results in the contingency table), so it's $O(n).$  Post-processing the table takes $O(rs) \le O(n)$ time assuming all of the $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are nonempty, which is almost always the case.

Comment: @Lucas Are you sure you don't have a O(n) term somewhere?

Comment: Thank you @whuber! My only doubt now is why it is $O(n)$, I would expect it to be $O(n^2)$ since you would have to check $n \choose 2$ pairs.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I don't think I have  a O(n) term. For this special case, the partitions contain exactly $r$ and $s$ elements (we can retrieve the full partition from them), and I found an equation that computes the Rand Index as a function of these elements. I proved it rigorously and also checked it computationally too, so I think it is correct.

Comment: How do you compute the intersections in less than O(n)? You will have to look at individual elements at some point.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse you don't have to compute the intersections for this case! I think I will write down the problem I'm working on and my solution in a cross-validated post (because it is more related to statistics), and then later I will add a link to it here.

Comment: I have strong doubts there. At some point you'll be using $X_i \cap Y_j$, which you don't get for free. Somewhere you *have* to look at the data, if you want to be generally useful.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I provide here https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.03738 and example of how the Rand index can be computed in $O(r+s)$ when the applied to change-point detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard approach takes O(n) to tabulate the data.

Then O(rs) to process each cell in the table once.

So the worst case probably is O(n²) with most implementations, assuming that each object is it's own cluster in both the ground truth and the clustering (in which in the most extreme case using the Rand index is pointless, and you will get a division by zero). A more useful number is O(N+rs) or just O(N) assuming that there are relatively few clusters and many points. A sparse matrix data structure can be used to bound the complexity to O(N).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Why does it take $O(n)$ to tabulate the data? Don't you have to check every pair, which would be $n \choose 2$?

Comment: I don't see where the $O(n^2)$ value comes from: could you explain?  Lucas, tabulation can be carried out in a single pass through the data: for each observation locate an address, based on its membership in the two partitions, that will be used to accumulate the count.  Increment that count.  With a hash table each operation is $O(\log(rs))$ but when there's $O(rs)$ storage and $r$ and $s$ are known in advance (or you have $O(n^2)$ storage) each operation is $O(1),$ leading to either $O(n\log(rs))$ or $O(n)$ timing.

Comment: Lucas tabulating the data itself is O(n). A matrix has O(1) random access, you need one for each item. Note that you do *not* tabulate pairs, you tabulate items. @whuber why would a hash table be $O(\log rs)$? It's not a tree map.

Comment: Good point.  In most practical cases you can take the hash lookup to be $O(1),$ but you need large amounts of RAM.  I had in mind using small amounts of storage for the table which would incur costs for chaining, expanding the table, etc. in the worst case.

Comment: If you know that n is an upper bound, you may get away with allocating a table of size 2*n (or some power of two close to this), and use open addressing. Not sure about worst case chain lengths; but at most n buckets can be in use, so the average chain length will likely be O(1), in particular while still building the hash. For practical purposes, of course, r and s will likely be known, and some value like min(r*s,n)*2 may be a better size estimate. Also, it would be possible to begin with a much smaller size (say, r*s/32), but rather than expanding the hash table, switch to a dense matrix.

Comment: Thank both of you for your answers, I understood why it is $O(n)$ now, I was confusing my self with checking every pair, and you clearly don't need that to build the table.